# Send e-mails in user's preferred language in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7

I have locale module enabled. But I don't see any options to have e-mails (Account activation, Welcome, Password Recovery) translated.

How do I send e-mails in the user's preferred language?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just in case someone needs it. Need to download the Internalization module http://drupal.org/project/i18n and enable the Variables translation submodule. Then you need to follow instructions here http://drupal.org/node/1113374 . To input the translation (or another version for another language) you need to switch your language to the one you want the translation for. And put the other language version into the field where the English version was.

Answer (score 2):

If the language you want to use is enabled on the site, you should be able to translate the message text in the Translate interface. Go to Configuration -> Translate interface. Under the Translate tab, type in the first few words of the message. Find the text you want and add a translation.

Comment: For the default text it works. But I have written my own version of the "Welcome (no approval required)" email in English (default language) and nothing of it comes up at the translation interface.

Comment: Hm. Tricky. I've noticed that the string you need to translate sometimes does not show up in the translate interface until the text has been generated on the site at least once, that is until the t() function has been run. Could be just coincidence of course. Do you have the i18n modules installed? In that case perhaps you could try refreshing the strings on the String tab of the translate interface.